# Generators for $PSL_2(F_5)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, symmetry

I am trying to show that $PSL_2(F_5)$ is isomorphic to $A_5$. I have shown that $|PSL_2(F_5)=60|$ I have found 2 matrices

$$
   A=
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
   0 & -1 \\
   1 & 0
  \end{array} \right]
$$
$$B=
  \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
   0 & -1 \\
   1 & 1
  \end{array} \right]$$

such that $A^2=B^3=(AB)^5= I_2$. Thus there is a homomorphism from $A_5 \to PSL_2(F_5)$. I want to show that $A$ and $B$ generate $PSL_2(F_5)$ which would imply that the homomorphism is an isomorphism.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could try determining the conjugacy classes of $PSL_2(F_5)$, say using Jordan normal form.

Answer (score 4):

Your homomorphisms is injective because its domain is a simple group. It follows from that that your two elements generate a subgroup of order 60 which is therefore the whole group.